# SSRS: Set report parameters as part of query

Tags: reporting-services

Is there any way i can SET the parameter value of report parameter in my SSRS query?
I want to reset the input parameter on the basis of certain condition. Is it possible inside the dataset query of ssrs report?

i have  parameter which i need to set the value of `@Text1`  input, something like following

```
IF @Flag = 1
 BEGIN
     SET @Text1 = @Text2
 END
   SELECT ..... FROM .... WHERE FirstName = @Text1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When SSRS processes your report, it simply replaces your parameter variables with values and executes the query (almost as if you had hard-coded the values).  So SQL Server will never see your `@Text1` variable and will throw an error when you try to `SET` it.

What you could do is `DECLARE` a new variable in your query, and use it to hold your parameter value.  Your example becomes something like:

```
DECLARE @Text1Holder VARCHAR(50) = @Text1;

IF @Flag = 1
 BEGIN
     SET @Text1Holder = @Text2
 END
   SELECT ..... FROM .... WHERE FirstName = @Text1Holder
```

Comment: Hmmmmm sure i will try this and let you know the result. Thanks :)